# How to handle error pages in Spring Boot 2.4.5?

Tags: spring-boot

I followed this guide to manage the error pages:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

and I wrote this code but it doesn't work:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=*******
spring.datasource.username=*******
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.datasource.schema = classpath:drop.sql, classpath:schema.sql
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=false
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.error.path=/error
```

ControlloPagineErrore:

```
public class ControlloPagineErrore implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp");
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
        if (status != null) {
            Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());
            if(statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                return "404"; // Pagina non trovata > 404.html
            }
            else if(statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "500"; // Errore interno del server > 500.html
            }
        }
        return "error";
    }
    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My webapp only reaches the error.html page and not 404.html.

1. How do i solve?
2. How can I test the 500 page on IntelliJ? How can I generate a desired internal server error?

**P.S.: I am a beginner.**

Comment: That guide is stupid... What they do is already supported out-of-the-box. They first disable this, and than do an attempt to shoehorn it in again. Ignore that guide and include an `404.html` or actually `<error-code>.html `for the specific error pages you want to display. These go in `src/main/resources/public/error` and will automatically be used. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling-custom-error-pages

Comment: This comment is the answer to the discussion. Thanks